# Application developed using jsp and online Mysql stopped working after deployment in jelastic

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, websocket, glassfish

I am developing web JSP application which is now working on my localhost using MySQL database (XAMPP). And it runs good on my PC. My IDE is Netbeans and i am using Glassfish 4.1. which is included into my IDE. To get my application working on Internet i need 2 things:

- online MySQL database
- online Glassfish server

Did anyone had anything similar to my problem? So far for server i have found [Jelastic](https://app.jelastic.elastx.net/) and for online free database [db4free](http://www.db4free.net/). So i need to get my app working just for few days for presentation so websites with 30 days trial are good option too. This database which i have found is very slow (phpmyadmin is loading several minutes etc.) and my application which is working localhost without any error is not working after deploying it on Jelastic.

**EDIT**

I have successfully set up my app working with 2 new problems.

- Google Charts are working localhost but not on Jelastic
- Connection to websocket

So i have in my JSP file included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

but it looks like same code on localhost working and on Jelastic not. Maybe i need to do it somehow else?

I use websocket where admin see when other users do some actions (like log file in real time) and that also working  localhost but on jelastic not. On localhost i used path `ws://localhost:8080/KukecDR/endpointserver` and now on jelastic i am using path `ws://kukecdr.jelastic.elastx.net:8080/KukecDR/endpointserver`

I did checked how to set up WebSocket in Jelastic [here](http://docs.jelastic.com/websockets-java) but i dont have that `gfcluster-config` in my glassfish admin console. I got `default-config` and `server-config` but no that `gfcluster-config`. I am using Glassfish 4.1. So basically i did succeed to move my project from localhost to "live version" but with few problems.

**EDIT2**

Google charts solved (had some package which was handled localhost with no errors but on jelastic had error and couldn't fetch data).

Any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, @Sl1mmm. db4free.net is a testing service which means it is not suitable for production.  If you need a MySQL database for production use, you can add [Database in Jelastic](http://docs.jelastic.com/add-database). Also see following topic which help you to configure [Java Connection to MySQL](http://docs.jelastic.com/connection-to-mysql).

Comment: Well, since i need this only for presentation, i would like to have some free online database (Mysql) and server which can run JSP pages. Buying server+database for 2,3 days for presentation is kinda lame.

Comment: Hello, @Sl1mmm. Jelastic provides 14 days trial period. What prevents you to use it fully?

Comment: @Aless Well i didn't knew that. Now i can get my app properly work. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Edited original post with new problems